# Print STDOUT to both file and STDOUT with perl

Tags: stdout, stdin

In one of the post, below method is suggested to capture STDOUT to a file without affecting logging at STDOUT (terminal).

```
open my $tee, "|-", "tee E:/log.txt";
```

For a sequence like below:

```
print $tee "Log1\n";
print $tee "Log2\n";
my $input = <STDIN>;
print $tee "Log3\n";
```

I don't see any message at terminal unless I provide the input. Once I type any character and press enter, then I see logs coming as

```
Log1
Log2
Log3
```

Is there a way such that I get first two outputs and then it waits for input and then the third output?

Or is there any way to capture STDOUT logs to a file while STDOUT logs keep coming on terminal too?

Answer (score 0):

Set your filehandle to unbuffered output using

```
$old_fh = select($tee);
$| = 1;
select($old_fh);
```

Comment: Or:         use IO::Handle;
        $tee->autoflush(1);

Comment: Thanks, this works as I expected. Could you please explain a bit, what is this doing? What does '$|=1' mean?

Comment: This is a feature deep down in the Unix C library, which is also used by Perl. In order to optimize resource usage, it will not write output right away, rather it waits until a buffer is full or until console input. The $| special variable can be used to switch off this behavior in Perl. See also here: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#Variables-related-to-filehandles.